# Handling input-stream overflow (zero-window) in java

Tags: java, sockets, input, tcp, buffer-overflow

We have a  system where there are 2 applications. One of these is a legacy application, for which we can't do any code changes. This application is sending messages to second application which is written in java. In our java code, we have set input stream buffer size equal to 1 MB as follows:

```
Socket eventSocket = new Socket();
eventSocket.setSendBufferSize(1024 * 1024);
```

Now the legacy application is sending messages of variable size. Most of the messages are smaller than 1 MB. But sometimes it is sending messages as large as 8 MB. Many times these messages are read successfully by the java application. But for some cases, following read operation is returning -1 value:

`read = stream.read(b, off, len - off);` ( here stream is an InputStream object)

As per Java API definition, InputStream read method returns -1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.

But this is an erroneous behavior. We have done snoop test using
wireshark to verify the exact messages that are exchanged between these two applications and found that java application has sent zero
window message few seconds before the time when input stream read
method has returned -1 value. At the time when this java api method
has returned -1, java application was sending ZeroWindowProbeAck
message to the legacy application.

**How should we handle this issue?**

As per https://wiki.wireshark.org/TCP%20ZeroWindow, zero window has following definition:

> What does TCP Zero Window mean?
>
> Zero Window is something to investigate.
>
> TCP Zero Window is when the Window size in a machine remains at zero for a specified amount of time.
>
> This means that a client is not able to receive further information at the moment, and the TCP transmission is halted until it can process the information in its receive buffer.
>
> TCP Window size is the amount of information that a machine can receive during a TCP session and still be able to process the data. Think of it like a TCP receive buffer. When a machine initiates a TCP connection to a server, it will let the server know how much data it can receive by the Window Size.
>
> In many Windows machines, this value is around 64512 bytes. As the TCP session is initiated and the server begins sending data, the client will decrement it's Window Size as this buffer fills. At the same time, the client is processing the data in the buffer, and is emptying it, making room for more data. Through TCP ACK frames, the client informs the server of how much room is in this buffer. If the TCP Window Size goes down to 0, the client will not be able to receive any more data until it processes and opens the buffer up again. In this case, Protocol Expert will alert a "Zero Window" in Expert View.
>
> Troubleshooting a Zero Window
>
> For one reason or another, the machine alerting the Zero Window will not receive any more data from the host. It could be that the machine is running too many processes at that moment, and its processor is maxed. Or it could be that there is an error in the TCP receiver, like a Windows registry misconfiguration. Try to determine what the client was doing when the TCP Zero Window happened.

Source: flukenetworks.com

Answer (score 2):

> Handling input-stream overflow (zero window) in Java

There is no such thing as 'input-stream overflow' in Java, and you can't handle zero window in Java either, except by reading from the network more quickly. Your title already doesn't make sense.

> We have done snoop test using wireshark to verify the exact messages that are exchanged between these two applications and found that java application has sent zero window message few seconds before the time when input stream read method has returned -1 value.

1. Neither Java nor the application send those messages. The operating system does.
2. The input stream of a socket returns -1 if and only if a FIN has been received from the peer, and that may in turn occur if and and only if the peer has closed the connection or exited (Unix). It doesn't have anything to do wth TCP windowing.

> At the time when this java api method has returned -1, java application was sending ZeroWindowProbeAck message to the legacy application.

No it wasn't. The operating system was, and it wasn't 'at the time', it was 'a few seconds before', accordingly to your own words. At the time when this Java method returned -1, it had just received a FIN from the peer. Have a look at your sniff log. There is no problem here to explain.

> As per [whatever], zero window has the following definition

Wireshark does not get to define TCP. TCP is defined in IETF RFCs. You can't cite non-normative sources as definitions.

> TCP Zero Window is when the Window size in a machine remains at zero for a specified amount of time.

For *any* amount of time.

> This means that a client is not able to receive further information at the moment, and the TCP transmission is halted until it can process the information in its receive buffer.

It means that the *peer* is not able to receive. It has nothing to do with the client or the server specifically.

> TCP Window size is the amount of information that a machine can receive during a TCP session

No it isn't. It is the amount of data the receiver is *currently* able to receive. It is therefore also the amount of data the sender is present allowed to send. It has nothing to do with the session whatsoever.

> and still be able to process the data.

Irrelevant.

> Think of it like a TCP receive buffer.

It *is* a TCP receive buffer.

> When a machine initiates a TCP connection to a server, it will let the server know how much data it can receive by the Window Size.

Correct. And vice versa. Continuously, not just at the start of the session.

> In many Windows machines, this value is around 64512 bytes. As the TCP session is initiated and the server begins sending data, the client will decrement it's Window Size as this buffer fills.

It has nothing to do with clients and servers. It operates in both directions.

> At the same time, the client is processing the data in the buffer, and is emptying it, making room for more data. Through TCP ACK frames,

Segments

> the client informs the server of how much room is in this buffer.

The receiver informs the sender.

> If the TCP Window Size goes down to 0, the client

The peer

> will not be able to receive any more data until it processes and opens the buffer up again. In this case, Protocol Expert will alert a "Zero Window" in Expert View.
>
> For one reason or another, the machine alerting the Zero Window will not receive any more data from the host.

For one reason only. Its socket receive buffer is full. Period.

> It could be that the machine is running too many processes at that moment

Rubbish.

> Or it could be that there is an error in the TCP receiver, like a Windows registry misconfiguration.

Rubbish. The receiver is reading more slowly than the sender is sending. Period. It is a normal condition that arises frequently during any TCP session.

> Try to determine what the client was doing when the TCP Zero Window happened.

That's easy. Not reading from the network.

Your source is drivel, and your problem is imaginary.

Comment: Hi EJP,I checked snoop test logs again for FIN message. I didn't find any such much. But I found that "FIN, ACK" message is exchanged for a number of times between two peers. These messages are exchanged more than half an hour before disconnection due to even before

Comment: Hi EJP,  Thanks for your response.  I checked snoop test logs again for FIN message. I didn't find any such much. But I found that "FIN, ACK" message was exchanged for a number of times between these two peers. Even these messages were exchanged more than half an hour before the  time when input stream "read" method returned -1 value. I found that these messages were exchanged a number of times after these applications reconnected again. How can we make receiver to read as fast as the data send by another application? Should we increase input buffer size or we have any other alternative?

Comment: You *are* increasing the input buffer size. I can't comment on code you haven't posted.

Comment: HI EJP,  This is a proprietary code, so I am not able to copy it here. Could you please answer for few  of my observations:
I checked cpu performance and found that for 90% of time cpu was in idle state. Also iostate doesn't show that other system resources are consumed too much. So I want to know  how the receiving thread is getting slower. Can you please give your suggestions for this?  Is it dependent on any network resource?

Comment: I got following output for iostate command on that machine, where this problem has occurred:   tty        sd1           sd2           sd3           sd4            cpu
 tin tout kps tps serv  kps tps serv  kps tps serv  kps tps serv   us sy wt id
   0   78 956   9  192    0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0   13  1  0 85
Thu Nov 12 00:04:49 2015
   0   29 1158   7   23    0   0    0    0   0    0    0   0    0   12  1  0 87

Answer (score -1):

We have created a solution, where we are waiting for input stream to get cleared by **waiting for  some time after this overflow problem** occurs. We have done code changes as follows:

```
int execRetries  = 0;
 while (true)
        {
            read = stream.read(b, off, len - off);

            if (read == -1)
            {
                if(execRetries++ < MAX_EXEC_RETRIES_AFTER_IS_OVERFLOW){
                    try {
                        Log.error("Inputstream buffer overflow occured. Retry no: " + execRetries);
                        Thread.sleep(WAIT_TIME_AFTER_IS_OVERFLOW);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                }
                else{
                    throw new Exception("End of file on input stream");
                }
            }
            else if(execRetries!=0){

                Log.info("Inputstream buffer overflow problem resolved after retry no: " + execRetries);
                execRetries  = 0;
            }
.....
}
```

Solution is sent to test server. **We are waiting to verify the end result whether this solution is working**.

Comment: It won't. Once you've read EOS from a socket, that's it. There will never be any more data. And sleeps in networking code are literally a waste of time: cargo-cult programming. You're barking up the wrong tree entirely.